# Laravel - Get route by a route name

Tags: laravel, routes, helper

`route('products.create')` returns full path like `http://myapp.dev/products/create`.

How do I get the actual route? Only this -> `products/create`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such functionality provided by Laravel at this point. However, you may try this:

```
$extra = URL::to('/');
$actual = route('products.create');
str_replace($extra, '', $actual);
```

That will remove the *unnecessary* base URL from your route URL.